# Phone not connecting in 4G

Tags: internet, 4g

I have, since almost one year, a **Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro** smartphone and never connected on 4G, in the tray bar there is always **H** or **H+** (in the previous phone I had it was almost always on 4G). My  ISP is [TIM](https://tim.it) and I set the APN to the recommended one but with no luck. I also set **Prefer 4G** from network settings but another time it didn't work.

How can I connect to 4G?

Comment: How old is your SIM card (old SIM cards don't support 4G). Are you aware that on some MNOs 4G is a special option that is not automatically included in every data plan? May be you have to change your contract and add this option additionally?

Comment: [FrequencyCheck](https://www.frequencycheck.com/carrier-compatibility/5GvPT53/xiaomi-redmi-note-6-pro-standard-edition-dual-sim-td-lte-global-32gb-m1806e7tg/telecom-italia-mobile-tim-italy) tells me that your phone is not compatible with the LTE bands used by TIM but check your model of the device on the website to double-check.

Comment: @Robert My sim card is less than one year old because I changed it for device compatibility. No, in the old phone it worked perfectly all the time, it doesn't have sense that it doesn't work on this one for this reason.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Oh I saw. I didn't know it couldn't support LTE, it's only two years old that model :( So I can't connect in 4G in any way?

Comment: So I searched deeper and I believe that if you have the Global version of RN6, it's supposed to have [compatibility with TIM](https://www.frequencycheck.com/compatibility/KXNWFWX/xiaomi-redmi-note-6-pro-global-dual-sim-td-lte-32gb-m1806e7tg-xiaomi-tulip/italy). I still recommend looking at the back of your phone, check your module there and search with it on the website. I do own a Redmi 5 Plus Global and it's compatible with TIM 4G.

Comment: If your phone doesn't have the LTE bands for TIM, there is no way you can connect in 4G.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Thank you